# How to aggregate data in hour based on timestamp in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe a day full from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59
the table bellow is just and example, I can't paste it here because it's too long.

```
id        sm_log_time                    score 1       score 2  
0         2020-04-15 15:25:49            10            10   
1         2020-04-15 15:38:55            10            10   
2         2020-04-15 15:52:01            10            10   
3         2020-04-15 16:05:07            10            10   
4         2020-04-15 16:18:13            10            10
```

And my desired dataframe is something like this. Score 1 and score 2 is sum based on minutes in an hour

```
id        sm_log_time                    score 1       score 2  
0         2020-04-15 15:00:00            100            200   
1         2020-04-15 16:00:00            230            200  
2         2020-04-15 17:00:00            200            300  
3         2020-04-15 18:00:00            100            300  
4         2020-04-15 19:00:00            100            300
```

Someone give me this for reference:

```
times = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp_col)
df.groupby([times.hour, times.minute]).value_col.sum()
```

Comment: try `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1h')`

Answer (score 0):

First setting index is necessary. Then use `resample` method of time series index:

```
df.set_index('sm_log_time').resample('H').sum().reset_index()
```

Result:

```
          sm_log_time  id  score 1  score 2
0 2020-04-15 15:00:00   3       30       30
1 2020-04-15 16:00:00   7       20       20
```

Please note also `id` is summed, You may drop it if not necessary. New row number of resulting dataframe is now in index.